# Disable ListBox Editing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have a list box connected to a database.
I dont want the user to be able to type their own text into the listbox, i just want them to be able to choose from the drop down box.

How do i go about doing this in Visual Studio 2010? 
Cant seem to find a property for it.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net?

Comment: winforms - vb.net.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going with WinForms here.
`ListBox` and `DropdownBox` (`ComboBox`) are 2 different controls.

In a `ListBox` you can't enter text by default, so I think you're talking about a `ComboBox` here.
That control has a property `DropDownStyle`. When you set that to `DropDownList`, the user can't enter his own text.

Comment: Ah sorry, Was a late night last night. Will check it out, thanks